# Dynamic Title in XML layout Android

Tags: android, layout, title

In my application i am getting the Title from xml code , so i have the titles in ArrayList and can set them to title bar in XML layout! but as you see in a picture its not shown correctly because of the number of words or size...i want to have the title in ***this size*** but in correct order , no problem for showing it as a half ! so actually how i can change the XML code to have title in center in same size?

[image]

and this is my XML code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/headerBar"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:contentDescription = "@string/headerBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/naviText"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/backBtn" />
```

the **navigation** goes for title bar !

Answer (score 1):

What's the containing ViewGroup? FrameLayout?

Anyways, I would consider a different approach. I would lean more towards a top layout like a LinearLayout (horizontal) or RelativeLayout. Use the header image as its background, and then put the divider below it. This way, you can wrap_content your TextView

Comment: I have tried this and its working in displaying the all text on the background ! its ok by now but the thing is that i dont want the text to increase the relativelayout's size! i mean no matter how many words are there , i want to display half of it and let the rest as ( ... )
how can i do this?

Comment: TextView has something to set ellipses. With RelativeLayout, you can anchor views to the left/right/top/bottom, and then set the other views. This would limit something like the TextView to the remaining space.  LinearLayout has a weird weights system. You can do something like set the total weight of the LinearLayout to a value, and divide that value between its children's views. You can do things like set one view to take up 25% of the space and the other at 75%. Sometimes you have to flip the numbers, but it works. RelativeLayout to me is a little less of a mystery box